# OpenX php file in images directory

Tags: openx

In my openx directory

> openx/www/image

I have a php file that looks like c7dc84ecdf4fee7.php

Should this file be there? or its a malicious file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default openx/www/images contains ,

openx/www/images/layerstyles/*

openx/www/images/robots.txt

openx/www/images/1x1.gif

Only Image Banners will be stored here .

.php maybe malicious code

Immediately remove that .php file